# Generate a sound wave in After Effects that changes colour over time via an expression

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

I'm trying to find a way to generate a sound wave animation where the colour of the wave being generated changes as the person speaking swaps over.  I can do this with text just fine, and I have expressions to switch over based on some keyframes, but I cannot work out how to do this on an audio waveform.

After Effects' built-in Audio Waveform plugin can switch colour, but it changes the entire waveform when you animated it.  I want existing waves to stay one colour when new audio after the keyframe should be a different colour.

I tried using Trapcode Particular with Sound Keys.  I analysed the amplitude of my audio, and made a null which is modified in the Y-axis as the amplitude changes.

I want the waveform to look as much as possible like the built-in Audio Waveform- ie an amplitude and time graph moving over time, and ideally would be symmetrical about its X axis.

I set Particular to emit a directional stream of Streaklet particles, and increased the Wind on the Y axis to "blow" them along.  But as they blow along, they compress down over time.

Example below - top line is Particular, lower line is Audio Waveform:

I've tried adjusting many other values - air resistance is zero, mass at very low numbers - nothing seems to achieve the right effect.

Is there a way to do this?  Or another way entirely?

Many thanks

Comment: I don't know, well, anything about the tools you are using, but looking at the video, are you sure it is getting shrunk down over time? It looks to me like it might be moving into the distance on the z-axis.